# Adding maven support for project messed up loading of images/working with paths

Tags: java, image, maven, netbeans, resources

I had a project which i moved to maven, since it makes it easy for me to work with dependencies , after i did that build works alright bud my execution stops at loading a resource (image) from one of my packages.Im lost since everything works well on old build without maven.

I load image

```
   primStage.getIcons().add(new Image(OpenChannel_Dynamic_Downloader.class
                                    .getResourceAsStream(Info.Resource.OCPI)));
```

Resource location is specified here

```
public static final String OCPI = "/openchannel_dynamic_downloader/resources/images/openChannelPlaceholderIcon.png";
```

My whole package structure is same , all the names everything.

Exception that i get is :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1110)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:694)
    at openchannel_dynamic_downloader.application.OpenChannel_Dynamic_Downloader.lambda$showLoginWindow$10(OpenChannel_Dynamic_Downloader.java:233)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Problematic line is the first code snipped. Has anyone seen this issue before? Do i ahve to change hwo i work with paths when i put in maven? Im pretty much a newbie to whole maven so woud be nice if you can help me with this since i expected this to work without an issue.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bisciak</groupId>
    <artifactId>OpenChannel_Dynamic_Downloader_MavenEnabled</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>OpenChannel_Dynamic_Downloader_MavenEnabled</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>openchannel_dynamic_downloader.application.OpenChannel_Dynamic_Downloader</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Tomas Bisciak's software</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>8.40.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.190</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.openjfx.backport</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjfx-78-backport</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-ea-b96.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

Image is correctly located at the specified package/location and code was not modified since my migration,is this maven related?

Package structure:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with Maven, all resources should be placed under `src/main/resources`. By resources, I mean every file that should be packaged into the final JAR, i.e. every file that should be present in the classpath.

Since you are using `Class.getResourceAsStream()` to access your images, they must reside under that folder.

As such, you should move your resources under `src/main/resources`. The final location for the image would be: `src/main/resources/openchannel_dynamic_downloader/resources/images/openChannelPlaceholderIcon.png`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to load images when working with **Maven** and **JavaFx** in this way: 
1) Put image into `src/main/resources/images/image.png`.
2) Create `javafx.scene.image.Image` object:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
String imageUrl = classLoader.getResource("images/image.png").toExternalForm();
Image image = new Image(imageUrl);
```